# c# File ReadAllText only reads first Char

Tags: c#

in a current development I'm stuck with a strang problem.

In a bunch of written files on my harddisk i want to read out their content and write it into a textbox. It seams very easy, but somehow i stuck in a catch:

The files are containing something like this: "`<LogItem><Row Number="0"><Column Name="object_id"><Old Value="2317"/><New Value="2317"/>`"

I read them with:

```
textBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(filetoread);
```

The result of this "ReadAllTest" is only the first Char "<" everything else in not written into the textbox. 
Manually I can read the file with the normal Editor and this shows the complete text.

Are there any traps or limitations a haven't seen?

Best regards

Comment: It sounds like you haven't seen the documentation for a start. Second, is your textbox big enough for all the text. Third, why a text box and not a rich textbox. Fourth, that text looks like xml, do you really want to show the xml in a textbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *could* be a problem of encoding... Rare but not impossible... Try, one at a time:

```
textBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(filetoread, Encoding.Unicode);

textBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(filetoread, Encoding.BigEndianUnicode);

textBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(filetoread, Encoding.UTF32);

textBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(filetoread, Encoding.UTF8);

textBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(filetoread, Encoding.Default);
```

Comment: @user2672560 Which one was? The first?

Answer (score 0):

If the answer by xanatos doesn't work, try this:

```
using (StreamReader read = new StreamReader(filetoread))
{
   textBox1.Text = read.ReadToEnd();
}
```

It doesn't use `File.ReadAllText()` as you can see.
And, this will work.

Comment: False. This returned the first char for me. Encoding.Unicode however does work. Encoding.UTF8 returns the first character when running File.ReadAllText or StreamReader.